# Converting custom nav bar to dropdown menu on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the navigation bar I made convert to a dropdown-menu when viewed on a smaller screen (like phones and tablets). The problem is, I didn't use the conventional bootstrap nav bar system, and just made my own. I know that the usual bootstrap solution involves using the nav classes, but I'm not really sure how I'd integrate those into my own code since I didn't use them to begin with. For tablets, I was hoping to have the main menu buttons hide into a dropdown menu with a toggle button, while keeping the logo there. Here is my code:

```
<header class="main-header" id="Navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <img class="HeaderLogo img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1499450095/Enpowered_Logo_k69cqw.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                        <p class="NavBarButtons"> WHY US </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p class="NavBarButtons"> FIX YOUR BILL </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p class="NavBarButtons"> HOW IT WORKS </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p class="NavBarButtons"> LEARN WITH US </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p class="NavBarButtons"> COMMERCIAL </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-4">
                        <p class="NavBarButtons"> LOG IN </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 md-offset-3">
                        <button class="SignUp"><b> UNLOCK YOUR POWER </b></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Since I used the grid system, everything collapses pretty well until a certain point, then the entire header completely messes up and stacks, which is why I wanted to try having the menu buttons go into a dropdown menu when that breakpoint is reached. Any help at all is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include some screen shots on issue and how you want to appear, that would help to understand well and quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose a lot of baked-in functionality when you try to do this outside a `.navbar` but it's manageable.  The `.navbar-collapse` component itself isn't directly tied to the use of the larger component; you just need to include the `<button>` and wrapper element for the collapse:

```
<header class="main-header" id="Navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img class="HeaderLogo img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1499450095/Enpowered_Logo_k69cqw.png">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar">-</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar">-</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar">-</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center" id="menu-collapse">
                        <div class="col-md-2"><p class="NavBarButtons">WHY US</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><p class="NavBarButtons">FIX YOUR BILL</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><p class="NavBarButtons">HOW IT WORKS</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><p class="NavBarButtons">LEARN WITH US</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2"><p class="NavBarButtons">COMMERCIAL</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><p class="NavBarButtons">LOG IN</p></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"><button class="SignUp"><b>UNLOCK YOUR POWER</b></button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

...

Where you run into problems (and why I would recommend using the whole `.navbar` structure, is that you need to style the aforementioned button and its various states.  You'll also need to address spacing concerns (the dropdown pushes elements down in this fashion).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty nasty, but.. You could do it with some adjustments to your code so that you'll end up with this:

```
<nav class="main-header navbar navbar-default" id="Navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-3 navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img class="HeaderLogo img-responsive" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/duocsoiqy/image/upload/v1499450095/Enpowered_Logo_k69cqw.png" style="width: auto;">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="text-center nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                    <p class="NavBarButtons"> WHY US </p>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-2">
                    <p class="NavBarButtons"> FIX YOUR BILL </p>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-2">
                    <p class="NavBarButtons"> HOW IT WORKS </p>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-2">
                    <p class="NavBarButtons"> LEARN WITH US </p>
                </li>
                <li class="col-md-2">
                    <p class="NavBarButtons"> COMMERCIAL </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-4">
                    <p class="NavBarButtons"> LOG IN </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 md-offset-3">
                    <button class="SignUp"><b> UNLOCK YOUR POWER </b></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's what I did:

1. give the `col-md-3` class `navbar-header`
2. In there add

   ```
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
   ```
3. Add `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">` around your `img`
4. the `col-md-6` column, add classes `collapse navbar-collapse` and
   `id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`
5. The div in that one add classes `nav navbar-nav`
6. Make the `header` a `nav` element
7. Give the `nav` classes navbar navbar-default
8. Remove the row
9. The div in the `col-md-6` column, remove the row and make it an `ul`
   Turn the `div`s in there into `li`s

Basically what you have done now is take the steps necessary to write a bootstrap nav. Take a good look at the example at [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)
You'll see that it actually doesn't use the grid system.

Keep in mind you need to include the bootstrap javascript to be able to use `toggle` functionality.

```
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also also, don't put `p` elements in your navigation. Paragraphs don't make any sense there.